# PHP and Prettier - not formatting .class files

Tags: php, vscode-extensions, prettier

I am having an issue in VS Code where prettier is not formatting .class files. It formats .php and .js files correctly. When I try to save a .class file I get an error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my .prettierrc file:

```
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.php", "*.class"],
      "options": {
        "tabWidth": 4,
        "braceStyle": "psr-2",
        "printWidth": 200
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.js"],
      "options": {
          "tabWidth": 2,
          "printWidth": 80
      }
  }
  ],
  "plugins": ["@prettier/plugin-php"]
}
```

And the error message:

```
["INFO" - 3:36:55 PM] Formatting file: 
["INFO" - 3:36:55 PM] Using config file at 'c:\directory\.prettierrc'
["INFO" - 3:36:55 PM] PrettierInstance:
{
  "modulePath": "c:\\directory\\node_modules\\prettier\\index.cjs",
  "importResolver": {},
  "callMethodResolvers": {},
  "currentCallMethodId": 66,
  "version": "3.0.3"
}
["INFO" - 3:36:55 PM] Using ignore file (if present) at c:\directory\.prettierignore
["INFO" - 3:36:55 PM] File Info:
{
  "ignored": false,
  "inferredParser": null
}
["WARN" - 3:36:55 PM] Parser not inferred, trying VS Code language.
["ERROR" - 3:36:55 PM] Failed to resolve a parser, skipping file. If you registered a custom file extension, be sure to configure the parser.
["INFO" - 3:42:05 PM] Using config file at 'c:\directory\.prettierrc'
```

Log entry on successful PHP formatting:

```
["INFO" - 3:43:43 PM] Using config file at 'c:\directory\.prettierrc'
["INFO" - 3:43:43 PM] Formatting file:///c%3A/directory/file.php
["INFO" - 3:43:43 PM] Using config file at 'c:\directory\.prettierrc'
["INFO" - 3:43:43 PM] PrettierInstance:
{
  "modulePath": "c:\\directory\\node_modules\\prettier\\index.cjs",
  "importResolver": {},
  "callMethodResolvers": {},
  "currentCallMethodId": 82,
  "version": "3.0.3"
}
["INFO" - 3:43:43 PM] Using ignore file (if present) at c:\directory\.prettierignore
["INFO" - 3:43:43 PM] File Info:
{
  "ignored": false,
  "inferredParser": "php"
}
["INFO" - 3:43:43 PM] Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used
["INFO" - 3:43:43 PM] Prettier Options:
{
  "filepath": "c:\\directory\\custodyview\\summaryview.php",
  "parser": "php",
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "plugins": [
    "c:\\directory\\node_modules\\@prettier\\plugin-php\\src\\index.js"
  ],
  "tabWidth": 4,
  "braceStyle": "psr-2",
  "printWidth": 200
}
["INFO" - 3:43:43 PM] Formatting completed in 42ms.
```

settings file:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "typescript.check.npmIsInstalled": false,
    // Points to the PHP executable.
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "files.eol": "\n",
    "files.associations": {
      "*.class": "php"
    },
    // Set the default
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    // Enable per-language
    "[javascript]": {
      "editor.formatOnSave": true,
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[php]": {
      "editor.formatOnSave": true,
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    },
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.printWidth": 400,
    "prettier.endOfLine": "lf",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom",
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "liveServer.settings.host": "",
    "[html]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "prettier.documentSelectors": [
      "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue,html,css,scss,less,json,md,mdx,graphql,yaml,yml,php,class}"
    ]
  }
```

As above. See relevant logs